# new Date() output is different on frontend and backend?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I have a variable, "today", which pulls the month, day, and year from a new Date() object, and creates a string MMDDYYYY.

This is how I implemented it on the front end:

```
    var today = new Date()
    console.log("today " + today)
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var newToday = mm + dd + yyyy;
    console.log("new today " + newToday)
```

And here is the output:

```
today Mon Jan 04 2021 17:58:39 GMT-0800 (PST)
new today 01042021
```

Ok, everything is fine, today is indeed the 4th.

Here is the backed implementation, in my Cloud Firestore scheduled function:

```
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    today = mm + dd + yyyy;
```

Almost identical, but when I run the cloud function, the function is writing to here:

[image]

notice the cloud function wrote to `../01052021`, but the output from the frontend means that the frontend is looking for data in `../01042021`.

Why does this discrepancy between frontend and backend happen? how can I fix it so when the day changes to 01/05 on the backend, the same happens on the frontend?

Comment: Have you checked the timezone of your cloud service? If you have different timezones a few hours can put one machine into a different day.

Comment: If you use `serverDateInstance.getTime()`, you can pass that to your Client-side `new Date(here)` then you should have the correct Client date and time.

Comment: @AJStacy It looks like this is probably it. When I see the log on the frontend, Im in PST, the backend is logging the next day without the timezone. Only thing I can think of is that the time on the backend is GMT? A few hours wouldn't make a difference at 6pm PST, but it is currently at 6pm PST. So that means the cloud function is HOURS ahead

Comment: @StackSlave can you make a full answer? This could be the issue im facing

Comment: When you save the times to your database make sure you are using `Date.now()` or `const dt = new Date; dt.getTime();` so its a UTC value. When extracting pass that timestamp into a Client side `const dt = new Date(yourAJAXResult);` then access `dt` like you normally would. Make sure `yourAJAXResult` is a Number, not a String.

Comment: @StackSlave sorry, I didn't add enough information in the question. The cloud function runs a function independent of the front end. When the database is updated with the information, the front end should (theoretically) change the date at the same time as the back end, so the fetching functionality will automatically read from the freshly written db done by the cloud function. I am not passing an Ajax result

Comment: Yeah... you would have to use AJAX to sync that up. It's not magic.

Comment: @StackSlave will look into it. thanks